# Why this code isn't uploading image?

Tags: php, ajax, image-uploading

Here is a code for uploading image using `ajax`. I have added `jQuery` library and `jQuery` form as well but this code neither gives me any error nor uploads image just uploading goes on and upload image starts running never to stop. Can't find whats wrong with this code.

`upload.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#photoimg').live('change', function()      { 
$("#preview").html('');
$("#preview").html('<img src="./img/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({
        target: '#preview'
}).submit();
});
}); 
</script>

<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
Upload your image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
</form>
```

`ajaximage.php`

```
<?php
include("/inc/connect.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
else if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
  $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
}
else
{
 //invalid ---
}


$path = "uploads/";

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
$name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

if(strlen($name))
{
list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
{
if($size<(1024*1024))
{
$actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
    $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
    {
    $sql=$db->prepare("UPDATE table SET profile_pic=:image_name WHERE username=:username");
                $sql->execute(array(':image_name'=>$actual_image_name,':username'=>$username));

echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."'  class='preview'>";
}
else
echo "failed";
}
else
echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
}
else
echo "Invalid file format..";   
}
else
echo "Please select image..!";
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? and did you start the session?

Comment: @Fred-ii- tried various like http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/latest/jquery.js and session is on

Comment: `.live` is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/live/ could be one of the reasons and make sure the folder has the right permissions to write to it. Use `.on` http://api.jquery.com/on/